# Can GraphDB workbench be used against an existing RDF4J server?

Tags: graphdb, rdf4j

Its not clear whether GraphDB-workbench (https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-workbench) can be used against an existing RDF4J install.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/1901

Comment: I added some notes above. To do that properly will take quite some development. But if it's acceptable if some menus lead to broken functionality, I think it should be easy to do. Rob, keep us posted.